# Find the range in which 80 percent of users are

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset as mentioned below. It has two columns `user` and `time`. I want to calculate the time range in which 80% of user are available. (80% is an arbitrary number)

```
+--------+------+
|  user  | time |
+--------+------+
| user1  |   23 |
| user2  |   30 |
| user3  |   17 |
| user4  |   33 |
| user5  |   47 |
| user6  |   33 |
| user7  |   34 |
| user8  |   42 |
| user9  |   33 |
| user10 |   17 |
| user11 |   43 |
+--------+------+
```

One way I [tried](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oizGxMFSXXK9yGNsEoPB3P/0) was with below query:

```
WITH rnt as (SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY time) Rn
             FROM table1),
            
percent as (
SELECT *, (Rn/(SELECT MAX(Rn)
           FROM rnt))*100 as user_share
FROM rnt)


SELECT *
FROM percent
WHERE user_share >=80
LIMIT 1
```

But I felt it to be very 'hardcoded' approach, if anyone could suggest any robust approach where I can get range of time as X and Y where Z% of users exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PERCENT_RANK()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#percent_rank) to calculate for `user_share`. See query below:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT 'user3' as user, 23 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user10' as user, 17 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user1' as user, 23 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user2' as user, 30 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user4' as user, 33 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user6' as user, 33 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user9' as user, 33 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user7' as user, 34 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user8' as user, 42 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user11' as user, 43 as time,
UNION ALL SELECT 'user5' as user, 47 as time
),

rnt as (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY time) Rn
    FROM sample_data
),

percent as (
    SELECT *, 
        (PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Rn ASC)) * 100 AS user_share
    FROM rnt
)

SELECT * 
FROM percent
WHERE user_share >=80
```

Output:

[image]